# PhpStorm: SSH-Connection failed. Error: 399

Tags: macos, ssh, phpstorm

I have encountered a strange error in PhpStorm that never happened before. Whenever I try to connect to a server via SSH, PhpStorm gives out an error that says only:

```
Connection to 'IP-Address' failed.
399
```

Nothing more. Only '399'. View also on this screenshot:

[image: View Screenshot]

The normal SSH-Protocol via the Mac-Terminal works fine and other programs like FileZilla do not have any trouble connecting via SSH.

I'm using:

- Mac-OS (Version 10.11.3)
- PhpStorm (Version 10.0.3)

What does that error mean? Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Enable extra logging and check idea.log file for any hints -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your help. I did that and the last entry corresponding to that error is: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 399 ... at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.fromBase64(Util.java:54) ... 43 more` Any idea what that means?

Comment: That's like some internal plugin error. Problem is -- maybe that error is completely unrelated... You better post whole log .. or just report it to JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Solved! Thank to LazyOne's comment I could google the problem and it turned out that it was caused by the known_hosts file (.ssh/known_hosts). Also have a look at ht following link: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12925] In my case it was possible to just replace the known_hosts file by an empty file. So now the SSH-Connection in PhpStorm works like ever before. Thanks again @LazyOne!